# UrlGenerationError: No route matches, missing required keys and link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I'm having issues with my static pages strategy on rails.

I have a controller that handles static pages. Basically, it reads templates in the `app/views/static` directory and render as asked. Like so:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def show
    templ = File.join(params[:controller], params[:page])
    puts params, templ
    render templ
  rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate => e
    if e.message =~ %r{Missing template #{templ}}
      raise ActionController::RoutingError, 'Not Found'
    else
      raise e
    end
  end
end
```

These are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static#show', page: 'home'
  get ':page', to: 'static#show', as: :static, constraints: { page: /a-zA-Z\-_\/+/ }
end
```

The root route works fine, I am able to access the view just fine. I get no errors.
Now, on my header partial, I have this, edited for simplicity/relevance:

```
<%= link_to('Home', static_path(:home)) %>
```

There is no other ruby code in the partial or the main template. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The error just does NOT make sense.

`ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"static", :format=>nil, :page=>:home} missing required keys: [:page]`

Where exactly is the required key missing from? I don't have any objects other or models.

Now this works just fine:

```
<%= link_to('Home', controller: 'static', action: 'show', page: 'home') %>
```

So how do I make static_path work like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a problem with the regexp your using for the constraint, I'd suggest dropping it from the route definition, as you already check if template is present in the controller.

Also, you should check out [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) gem which handles creating static pages quite nicely.

Comment: Dropping the regex fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be:

```
<%= link_to 'Home', static_path("home") %> #-> try passing a string, rather than symbol
```

This *should* allow you to reference the required path

--

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def show
    templ = File.join(params[:controller], params[:page])
    puts params, templ
    render templ
  rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate => e
    if e.message =~ %r{Missing template #{templ}}
      raise ActionController::RoutingError, 'Not Found'
    else
      raise e
    end
  end
end
```

I would personally make this a lot simpler:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render "pages#{params[:page]}
  end
end
```

Comment: I couldn't get any combination of string, hash, array, etc working inside of static_path().

I also couldn't get your new controller working, pageshome. i tried pages##{...} for pages#home, but couldn't be bothered with working out new errors. dropping the regex from the route worked.

Comment: lol okay at least you're honest! Thanks for the update - I sincerely hope it continues to work for you!